# Trouble in pandas library while generating a new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to Generate a new column "Delay" from the existing columns. And I'm getting this error.
[image: Error in code]

Comment: Your column `'clear_date'` is a datetime type, while `'due_in_date'` is a float. You should convert them to the same type, but without knowing what your data is, I cannot say how you should do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to convert your `due_in_date` column to [datetime dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

```
dtrain['due_in_date'] = pd.to_datetime(dtrain['due_in_date'])
```